# Opening a JSF2 Facelets page results in a 404 on a JSP file

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I created a new project as this tutorial  [JSF Tools tutorial - Build a JSF 2.0 application](http://www.4shared.com/photo/39FUsNfF/what.html)

When I try to run it by right clicking on `m.xhtml` and selecting run on server, I got a 404 error on `m.jsp`.

The URL in browser address bar is :http://localhost:8080/Marwa/m.jsf

The error message says [HTTP Status 404 - /Marwa/m.jsp](http://www.4shared.com/photo/39FUsNfF/what.html)

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>Marwa</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>m.xhtml</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
   <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
   <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for a JSP file instead of a Facelets file.

JSP was the default view technology in old JSF 1.x. This problem thus suggests that you're actually using JSF 1.x or are running JSF 2.x in JSF 1.x modus.

Make sure that you've really JSF 2.x libraries there. You can check the exact JSF version by reading the server startup log, or by extracting the JSF JAR file with a zip tool and reading MANIFEST file. You can also just re-download the right version at http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html (or http://javaserverfaces.java.net/ for another implementation). Make sure that you get the 2.x version.

Also make sure that `faces-config.xml` is declared conform JSF 2.x spec version. It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Config here -->

</faces-config>
```

If your Eclipse didn't do this all automatically, then you're apparently using an outdated Eclipse version. Builtin JSF2 support was introduced in Eclipse Helios (3.6) for Java EE for the first time. You can get the most recent version at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ which is currently Indigo SR2 (3.7.2).

Comment: Well, then there's still something wrong. What MyFaces version is printed in server's log? Any warnings in the server's log? How about when you open the page in a real webbrowser? And with the `/faces` URL? http://localhost:8080/Marwa/faces/m.xhtml

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/photo/G42R9jWj/jsf.html and my war file http://www.4shared.com/file/rVmt8eQ5/Marwa.html
when i use this URL localhost:8080/Marwa/faces/m.xhtml the text only apear and any jsf component doesn't

Comment: The server log tells that you're using Mojarra 1.2_13. You need 2.x. Upgrade the libraries. Did you understand the answer?

Comment: ok BalusC, i understand what didi you say and i use myfaces-core-assembly-2.1.7-bin.zip , eclips helios 3.6 and tomcat 6 but it still tells "Mojarra 1.2_13" but when i add jsf-facelets.jar file it is work but it can't understand <h:head><h:body>